# Retrieve 'Time' of Database MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, time

I'm trying to recover hours of the database, however is going the following exception:

> java.sql.SQLException: java.sql.SQLException: Bad format for Time
>   '13:00:00.000' in column 5

The line of exception is this:

```
Compromisso line = new Compromisso();
line.setHour (rs.getTime ("hour"));
```

Class compromisso:

```
//Using java.sql.Time
private Time hour;
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please share your table's structure and your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the type in the database.

Probably it is a `varchar` or `Date` or `timestamp`. So it is not possible to retrieve it as `Time`. It must be of type `time`

[Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-type-conversions.html) you can find the conversion table between java types and mysql column types.